# Azimuth coming back as 0

Tags: android, android-sensors, azimuth

I am trying to get the azimuth of the users phone when they take a picture. However, when I put the azimuth to the screen just for debugging purposes currently, it always comes back at 0.0. I am new to using Sensors so I am trying to figure this out. My code is

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    double latitude, longitude;
    if (mGpsLocationTracker.canGetLocation()) {
        latitude = mGpsLocationTracker.getLatitude();
        longitude = mGpsLocationTracker.getLongitude();
    } else {
        latitude = 0;
        longitude = 0;
    }
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "" + latitude + ", " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    getDirection ();

    Toast.makeText(this, Float.toString(degree), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void getDirection() {
    SensorManager mySensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    List<Sensor> mySensors = mySensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
    if(mySensors.size() > 0){
        mySensorManager.registerListener(mySensorEventListener, mySensors.get(0), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }
}

/*
DOES NOT WORK. NEED TO FIX
 */
private SensorEventListener mySensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener(){

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        float radianValue = Math.round(event.values[0]);
        degree = (float) Math.toDegrees(radianValue);
        if (degree < 0.0f) {
            degree += 360.0f;
        }

    }
};

public void takePicture (View view) {
    dispatchTakePictureIntent();
}
```

Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the orientation sensor return the angle in degrees? You're assuming radians and converting to degrees.  Given that though, it still should't give you 0.

Answer (score 0):

TYPE_ORIENTATION is depreciated and does not give the correct result 
if the device is not flat. You need to use `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` and `TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD` to obtain the `rotation matrix` and then call `remapCoordinateSystem` before calling `getOrientation`.